# Sorting rows into groups based on shared values

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I have a CSV with a large number of rows, from a user-submitted form.  Each row includes a user email, and a field for them to list other user emails in their group.  I've written a short script so far using Python and pandas that loads the CSV into a dataframe and cleans up entries.

I want to sort the rows by group, but am running into a few conceptual problems.  Since it's user-entered, the list is not necessarily complete or correctly spelled.  What's the best way to deal with this?  I'm entirely new to parsing data like this and rather inexperienced overall.

Here's some example data to show what I mean:

```
email,group
user1@a.com, "['user4@b.com','user3@c.com']"
user2@a.com,
user3@c.com, "['user1@a.com']"
user4@b.com, "['user1@a.com','user3@b.com']"
```

So here user1, user3, and user4 are in a group.  The problem is that user3 only listed user1.

My first thought was to append the submitting user's email to the group list and then sort the list and then column alphabetically.  However, that only works if everyone's group entries are complete.

I'd like not to pick out 200 groups by hand, but I'm lost as how to proceed.
This is my current plan in pseudocode:

```
data # dataframe containing imported CSV
sorted_groups # result dataframe with equivalent rows, but sorted into groups
sort(data) by len(data[group])
for each row in data:
    append row to sorted_groups
    search for rows where email == entry in groups
    append matching rows to sorted_groups
    remove matching rows from data
    remove initial row from data
```

This will definitely fail on misspellings, and only works if at least one person in the group got everything right.  It's the best I have at the moment, though.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything, and point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how of your data is stored, so I'm writing this assuming you have a list of rows of data, and each row contains all of the email addresses entered in the form.  e.g.,

```
rows = [['user1@a.com','user4@b.com','user3@c.com'],
        ['user2@a.com'],
        ['user3@c.com', 'user1@a.com'],
        ['user4@b.com','user1@a.com','user3@b.com']]
```

I'm also assuming that each user belongs to one and only one group, each user has submitted the form, and each user did not misspell their email.

We can obtain a set of valid email addresses using

```
  valid = {row[0] for row in rows}
```

We can build a dictionary mapping users to groups, merge groups as we go, and remove invalid emails.

```
ugDict = {}

for row in rows:
  mergedGroup = set(row) & valid
  for user in row:
    if user in ugDict:
      mergedGroup |= ugDict[user]
  for user in mergedGroup:
    ugDict[user] = mergedGroup
```

This will result in a mapping from users to groups, and will include any mistyped email addresses.  You'll have to decide how to validate emails -- you might just want to ignore them.

Now, to get a sorted list of groups, create a set of all groups, and use the sorted function.

```
sortedGroups = sorted({frozenset(g) for g in ugDict.values()})
```

frozenset(g) makes python's set object hashable (i.e. sortable).

The result?

```
sortedGroups = [frozenset({'user2@a.com'}),
                frozenset({'user1@a.com', 'user3@b.com', 'user4@b.com'})]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think a dictionary will definitely be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, my edit got eaten by the time limit.  

    Regarding misspellings, I can make the safe assumption that their own email is correct.  So with this code, the first user in each row would become the key for an entry, correct?  In that case, if the user's own email is first in the row, all entries should be valid.  (If that's not the case it won't be the end of the world).

    I do also have other data associated with each user.  It seems the best way to handle that is to sort them out in groups, then add that information back to the rest of the data.

Comment: With this code, every email gets an entry in the dictionary, pointing to the group to which it belongs, regardless of whether or not they are user who entered the row.

Comment: Will every user fill out the form?  This would give a definitive yes/no on email validity.  If so, you could remove any entries which are invalid with something like mergedGroup = (mergedGroup & valid)

Comment: Yes, every user has entered at least their basic information.

One more question (thanks for the great help so far!):
In that second snippet of code, valid would be a string containing a specific user's valid email?

Comment: "valid" would be a set containing all valid emails.  In my example, this can be built from the "rows" container:  valid = {row[0] for row in rows]